# How to exclude occluded objects using OpenCV?

Tags: java, opencv, android

I am a student who is preparing to participate in a competition that involves using libraries such as OpenCV for recognition and processing. I have been learning the basics of OpenCV for over a month now and I have encountered a very tricky problem. I am able to use OpenCV to recognize polygons that have five random types and seven colors. I have already solved the problem of identifying the colors and shapes, but I do not know how to exclude the polygons that are occluded. Please see the second column for more details.

I'm trying to use the Android version of OpenCV to solve the problem of polygon recognition. Currently, the method used is to obtain a binary image using the `inRange()` method, then use the `findContours()` method to find contours, perform opening and closing operations on the obtained contours, and then use the `approxPolyDP()` method for polygonal approximation. Finally, use the `convexHull()` method to detect the corners and determine the type of polygon. This method can recognize simple polygons, but it also recognizes polygons covered by foreground, which are invalid (should be excluded). What should I do to exclude these covered polygons?

**Example Image:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijx2S.jpg)

Could someone please assist me? Thank you very much!